# Chamar função somente quando a anterior encerrar

Tags: javascript

eu tenho 2 funções sendo chamadas dentro de outra, o problema que a segunda função depende de alguns elementos que vem da primeira função. A 1° função faz uma requisição ajax que leva um certo tempo em segundos, e o problema estar ai. Esta indo para segunda função sem antes encerrar a primeira, e isso prejudica o funcionamento da segunda função.
Exemplo:

```
function gerador(){
          funcao1();
          funcao2();
 }
```

tem alguma forma de so chamar a função 2 quando encerrar a função 1? lembrando que eu não posso alterar a estrutura das funções, apenas posso chamar elas. Então tenho que ter uma solução fora delas.

Comment: O que você descreve é um caso de [Problema XY](https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). O AJAX tem mecanismo próprio para você detectar o sucesso da requisição e executar algo (`onreadystatechange `). Uma  pesquisada por AJAX aqui no site vai ter exemplos. Queira fornecer um [mcve] do problema, se os posts atuais do site não forem suficientes. Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente uma função assíncrona terá que fazer uso ou de `callback`, ou de `promise`.

Como na pergunta não foi especificado qual é o caso, vou ter que usar um exemplo genérico.

Se a sua função utiliza callbacks, você provavelmente terá que passar a `funcao2` como parâmetro para a `funcao1`, dessa forma quando a funcao1 terminar de rodar, ela pode invocar a funcao2 para ser executada logo em seguida:

```
function gerador() {
    funcao1(retornoDaFuncao1 => funcao2(retornoDaFuncao1));
}
```

Agora se você está trabalhando com promises, você pode utilizar o callback dentro método `then` para invocar a funcao2:

```
function gerador() {
    funcao1().then(retornoDaFuncao1 => funcao2(retornoDaFuncao1));
}
```

Ou então utilizar os modificador `async` na sua função, que permite pausa-la até que uma promise termine de executar com o comando `await`. Note que isso só é possível se o retorno da funcao1 for um objeto do tipo `Promise`:

```
async function gerador() {
    var retornoDaFuncao1 = await funcao1();
    funcao2(retornoDaFuncao1);
}
```